# How to compare two JSON Strings that contains array with mixed elements?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying compare two json string with mixed elements in array. I found many answers([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655404/how-to-compare-two-json-strings-for-equality-using-gson),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214108/getting-a-diff-of-two-json-strings-using-java-code)) how compare two json but not with array. You can help me?

My code:

Passed

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node1 = mapper.readTree("{\"a\" : [{\"a\" : 2},{\"s\" : 5}], \"b\" : 2}");
    JsonNode node2 = mapper.readTree("{\"b\" : 2, \"a\" : [{\"a\" : 2},{\"s\" : 5}]}");
    assertThat(node1.equals(node2), is(true));
}
```

Failed, but why? How can compare json?

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode node1 = mapper.readTree("{\"a\" : [{\"a\" : 2},{\"s\" : 5}], \"b\" : 2}");
    JsonNode node2 = mapper.readTree("{\"b\" : 2, \"a\" : [{\"s\" : 5},{\"a\" : 2}]}");
    assertThat(node1.equals(node2), is(true));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not surprised by this. The ordering of JSON properties is normally not considered to be important - whereas the ordering of elements in a JSON array *is* considered important. Why do you consider it *unimportant*?

Comment: @JonSkeet i received similar json from other server and array elements always in a different order. But how i can compare json in this case?

Comment: Well, is there something simple you could sort the array by?

Comment: @JonSkeet how i can get array?

Comment: Well have you looked at the documentation for JsonNode? At this point the question doesn't seem to be as much about comparison as basic use of the API.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet, I am found lib with `org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONCompare` class where can compare JSON with different elements order in array