# print the difference between two json arrays

Tags: java, arrays, json, guava

I need to print the difference between two json array i am using

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType();
Map<String, Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(jsonElement1, mapType);
Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(jsonElement2, mapType);
MapDifference diff = Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap);
```

The above code was working fine if it a json string object, but it is throwing error

`com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 now.`

How to print the difference between these two json array

Comment: It would be helpful to include the JSON arrays you're testing on.

Comment: @px06 that is very large

Comment: @px06 this is a sample [{"ind":"","Cars":[{"His":[{"cost":0.0,"charge":0.0,"start":{"code1":"B","sCode":"A","dateTime":"Feb 11, 2017 8:00:58 AM","cNote":"","vStation":{"s33":"BECKER","a.....}]]]

Comment: You should probably use an appropriate tool for this complex task. something like [what is suggested on Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17812/26414).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting a diff of two JSON strings using Java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214108/getting-a-diff-of-two-json-strings-using-java-code)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a related question which should provide you with direction: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17812/java-library-that-diffs-json-and-generates-what-was-added-deleted-modified